# ClientError when calling get_execution_role() in aws sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have some really simple code here. It worked yesterday, but not today.

In a Jupiter notebook I call:

```
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
role = get_execution_role()
```

Then I get this massive error, but the gist of it is:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

The rest of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6f21dcc3c42a> in <module>
      1 from sagemaker import get_execution_role
----> 2 role = get_execution_role()

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in get_execution_role(sagemaker_session)
   4671     if not sagemaker_session:
   4672         sagemaker_session = Session()
-> 4673     arn = sagemaker_session.get_caller_identity_arn()
   4674 
   4675     if ":role/" in arn:

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in get_caller_identity_arn(self)
   3699             "sts",
   3700             region_name=self.boto_region_name,
-> 3701             endpoint_url=sts_regional_endpoint(self.boto_region_name),
   3702         ).get_caller_identity()["Arn"]
   3703 

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    506                 )
    507             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 508             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    509 
    510         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    909             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    910             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 911             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    912         else:
    913             return parsed_response

ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

I'm really far away from being an aws guru. So the huge error above from doing something simple like trying to get a role seems unreasonable.

Has anyone any experience with issues like this?

Answer (score 2):

[get_execution_role()](https://www.reddit.com/r/MaraudersGame/comments/y92hb9/the_reverse_airlock_camp_strat_you_didnt_know_you/) makes [various AWS API calls](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/adbe733c2a33af80ebd4392cf6961a49670e429e/src/sagemaker/session.py#L3674-L3708). The error indicates that your AWS credentials have expired.

If this notebook is hosted by SageMaker, I would log back into the AWS console and relaunch the notebook. Notebooks will automatically refresh the credentials they use, but this will fail if the notebook was open for a long time and your AWS session expired.